# Rename an existing file with CMake's install command

Tags: cmake

After building the project there is a `tensorflowd.dll` (installed by CMake) file which I would like to rename to `tensorflow.dll` file in an additional CMake install step. Is it possible to just rename a file (without installing it as a part of the same command?)

Or *must I* to do the renaming as a part of installing the `tensorflowd.dll` file itself?

`install_lib` macro mentioned in the comments:

```
#general macro suitable for small libs where you don't want to pick and choose which dlls get installed
#separates all dlls into two lists and if debug versions are present it uses that or if it's not
# it uses the release ones instead
function(INSTALL_LIB libname)

    if(NOT "${${libname}_FOUND}" STREQUAL "TRUE")
        message("Library ${libname} is not present and cannot be installed.")
        return()
    endif()


    FILELIST(files "${${libname}_BINARY_DIRS}")


    #filter out non dll files
    foreach(file ${files})

        string(REGEX MATCH "^.*.dll$" result ${file})

        if(NOT result STREQUAL "")
            list(APPEND dll_files ${file})
        endif()

    endforeach()

    #message("${files}")

    #find if it has debug or is it only release dll that is present..
    foreach(file ${dll_files})

        string(REGEX MATCH "^.*d\\.dll$" result ${file})

        if(result STREQUAL "")
            list(APPEND optimized_libs ${file})
        else()          
            list(APPEND debug_libs ${file})
        endif()

        #workaround for edge case with libs ending with 'd' and debug versions with 'dd'
        #upon detecting XXXdd.lib the coresponding XXXd.lib must be already in optimized_libs
        #so take it from there and place it into correct list.
        string(REGEX REPLACE "^(.*d)d\\.lib$" "\\1" dd_result ${file})
            #message("${filename} ${dd_result}")

        if(NOT dd_result STREQUAL "" AND NOT ${dd_result} STREQUAL ${file})
            #message("${filename} ${dd_result}")
            list(REMOVE_ITEM debug_libs "${dd_result}.dll")
            list(APPEND optimized_libs "${dd_result}.dll")
        endif()

        set(dd_result "")
        set(result "")

    endforeach()

    list(LENGTH debug_libs debug_length)
    list(LENGTH optimized_libs optimized_length)

    #If there are debug version but their count is not on par with release version, raise a red flag.
    if(NOT "${debug_length}" EQUAL "${optimized_length}" AND "${debug_length}" GREATER 0)
        message(WARNING "Counts of debug and optimized dlls of library ${libname} are different from each other..")
    endif()

    if("${debug_length}" GREATER 0)   

        foreach(item ${debug_libs})
            install(FILES ${${libname}_BINARY_DIRS}/${item} DESTINATION Debug           CONFIGURATIONS Debug)
        endforeach()

        foreach(item ${optimized_libs})
            install(FILES ${${libname}_BINARY_DIRS}/${item} DESTINATION RelWithDebInfo  CONFIGURATIONS RelWithDebInfo)
            install(FILES ${${libname}_BINARY_DIRS}/${item} DESTINATION Release         CONFIGURATIONS Release) 
        endforeach()

    else()

        foreach(item ${optimized_libs})
            install(FILES ${${libname}_BINARY_DIRS}/${item} DESTINATION Debug           CONFIGURATIONS Debug)
            install(FILES ${${libname}_BINARY_DIRS}/${item} DESTINATION RelWithDebInfo  CONFIGURATIONS RelWithDebInfo)
            install(FILES ${${libname}_BINARY_DIRS}/${item} DESTINATION Release         CONFIGURATIONS Release) 
        endforeach()

    endif()
endfunction()
```

Comment: Not sure what do you actually want. Your write "installed by CMake", but CMake simply does what you ask it. I *guess* you install debug variant of "tensorflow" library. Why do not change name of the file which is built? So it will be installed with a proper name. More background, please.

Comment: I wanted to do it this way because in our CMake system for installing 3rd party libs we have an `install_lib(lib_name)` macro which for some library `libX`'s `bin` folder installs the `libXd.dll` to the app's Debug directory and `libX.dll` to the Release directory. I wanted to keep using this macro with the tensorflow library so in the tensorflow bin folder there are 2 files: `tensorflowd.dll`, `tensorflow.dll`. But unfortunately the application tries to load the file named `tensorflow.dll` even in Debug mode, so the file `tensorflowd.dll` which is actually installed needs to be renamed.

Comment: Em? Do you ask us how to fix outcome of `install_lib` macro which we have never see? And how do you want to install `tensorflowd.dll` file as `tensorflow.dll`, as you already have this file in the same folder (in Release build)?

Comment: The debug build is in the bin/Debug folder and the release build is in the bin/Release folder so the files will not clash. In the original question I was just asking whether it is possible to rename an existing file without installing it (which I would still like to know). As I see it, I could either write my own special `install_tensorflow` macro or just use `install_lib` and rename `tensorflowd.dll` to `tensorflow.dll` afterwards as a special step (if that is possible with CMake's install). I appreciate your help and patience, this may be a bit convoluted.

Comment: "whether it is possible to rename an existing file without installing it" - Yes, it is possible to rename a file at **build** stage, but I don't know whether `install_lib` will work correctly after that renaming. The better approach seems to copy the file with a new name (so older file will be used by `install_lib`, and it won't care about the new file. On the other side, if you want to perform additional actions during the project's **installation**, you may use `install(SCRIPT)` or `install(CODE)` flow of [install](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/command/install.html) command.

Comment: Thanks, you 've been very helpful. I ended up just using `install(CODE "FILE(RENAME bin/Debug/tensorflowd.dll bin/Debug/tensorflow.dll)")` until I come up with a better solution. Feel free to post the last comment as an answer and I will accept it.